# Send Mouse commands to PC with Raspberry Pi over the network

Tags: keyboard, mouse, networking

Is it possible to have a Raspberry Pi connected to a CCTV recorder via USB and send mouse input commands over the network?

The video feed from the CCTV recorder is displayed on a TV with in the house, and there is no way to switch between cameras with out going into the room where the CCTV recorder is kept and changing it from there. I would like to connect the Raspberry Pi to the CCTV recorder via the USB port and connect the RPi to the network so a program can connect to the RPi and send mouse commands to the CCTV recorder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to this was the Teensy board. I ordered the Teensy 3.1 with the  WIZ820IO and the WIZ820_SD_ADAPTOR, this worked a treat. A very useful piece of hardware. Thank you @Rob

Answer (score 1):

Try Synergy, it allows to use one mouse on many computers so maybe it will do what you want http://synergy-project.org/

Comment: Sorry but Synergy won't work in this situation because the CCTV recorder doesn't allow any software to be installed on it. You can only control the system with a mouse and keyboard via USB ports. I was thinking of connecting a RPi to the CCTV recorder using a USB cable and plugging the RPi into the router. I would like to know if a custom iOS app can connect to the RPi and send mouse input commands so that the RPi can transmit those commands to the CCTV recorder. Basically creating a complicated WIFI mouse.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi cannot act as a USB client only a host. Try looking at Teensy a very cheap arduino type device that comes with HID (mouse/keyboard) client support built in. https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/